# Rails route constraint for base64 encoded parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following route:

```rb
get '/:id', to: 'articles#show'
```

How do I have the route only match if the `:id` is a base64 encoded string? I've tried regexp unsuccessfully.

**EDIT:** I've tried using the regex suggested in one of the responses.

```
get /:id, to: 'articles#show', constraints: { id: /^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{3}=)?$/}
```

This leads to the following error in Rails:

```
Regexp anchor characters are not allowed in routing requirements:
/^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{3}=)?$/
```

Comment: I think it would be perhaps easier to check that in the controller. You could use a before_action filter and implement a method such as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476873/check-if-string-is-base64

Comment: Think it's possible to create custom route constraints as an alternative to using regex. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints

Answer (score 1):

From the Rails routing guide located at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/routing.html

```
get '/:id', to: 'articles#show', requirements: {id: **Your Regex**}
```

This route would only hit if the :id parameter hit on the Regex.

As for a regex that will successfully match a base64 string, answers to the following StackOverflow question provide lots of options.
[RegEx to parse or validate Base64 data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475074/regex-to-parse-or-validate-base64-data)

Update:
Remove the anchor characters from your Regex.
Source: [Rails custom route with constraints - regexp anchor characters are not allowed in routing requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222382/rails-custom-route-with-constraints-regexp-anchor-characters-are-not-allowed-i)

Comment: I tried this and didn't work. I've updated my original question.

Comment: @GeekJock I'm a regex rookie but it looks like Google had a hit that could lead you in the right direction. I've updated the answer.